# Go interface for ordered types that can be used outside a type constraint?

Tags: sorting, go, generics, interface

I want to be able to create a struct that has a field that can hold any type of value as long as the type can be compared with the usual comparison operators (`<`, `<=`, `>`, etc...). I know that there is `contraints.Ordered`, but that interface is limited to being used as a type constraint.

Here is an example of what I want to use this interface for:

```
func TestMergeSort(t *testing.T) {
    type TestCase[T constraints.Ordered] struct {
            input []T
            expected []T
    }
    intTests := map[string]TestCase[int] {
            "#1": {
                    input: []int{3,2,5,1,4,6},
                    expected: []int{1,2,3,4,5,6},
            },
    }
    stringTests := map[string]TestCase[string] {
            "#2": {
                    input: []string{"hello","bonjour"},
                    expected: []string{"bonjour","hello"},
            },
    }

    // test int sorting
    for name, test := range intTests {
        t.Run(name, func(t *testing.T) {
            output := MergeSort(test.input)

            if !cmp.Equal(test.expected, output) {
                t.Fatalf(`Expected %v got %v`, test.expected, output)
            }       
        })
    }
    // test string sorting
    for name, test := range stringTests {
        t.Run(name, func(t *testing.T) {
            output := MergeSort(test.input)

            if !cmp.Equal(test.expected, output) {
                t.Fatalf(`Expected %v got %v`, test.expected, output)
            }       
        })
    }
}
```

**I want to be able to group the int and the string test cases under a single variable**. But that doesn't seem possible using generics with the `constraints.Ordered` constraint, because I must instantiate the generic type before I can use it.

Ideally, I'd want to reduce it to something like this:

```
func TestMergeSortTable(t *testing.T) {
    // What I'm looking for is something that can replace the `Sortable` interface example below
    type TestCase struct {
        input []Sortable
        expected []Sortable
    }
    tests := map[string]TestCase {
        "#1": {
            input: []int{3,2,5,1,4,6},
            expected: []int{1,2,3,4,5,6},
        },
        "#2": {
            input: []string{"hello","bonjour"},
            expected: []string{"bonjour","hello"},
        },
    }

    // test int and string sorting in a single loop
    for name, test := range tests {
        t.Run(name, func(t *testing.T) {
            output := MergeSort(test.input)

            if !cmp.Equal(test.expected, output) {
                t.Fatalf(`Expected %v got %v`, test.expected, output)
            }       
        })
    }
}
```

PS: Function signature for `MergeSort` in case it's needed

```
func MergeSort[T constraints.Ordered](arr []T)(res []T) {
    // sorting logic here
}
```

Comment: "I must instantiate the generic type before I can use it" you can have more than one type in a generic.  For example, https://go.dev/play/p/tdWa-Qfb-pQ you can use generics like this.  I have a feeling you're thinking of your experience with dynamically typed languages, and trying to apply that to a very different Go typing system.

Comment: @CeriseLimón added the testing logic, although I'm not sure if it's that relevant to the question at hand

Comment: @erik258 Yes your assumption was correct, my experience is mostly from dynamically typed languages.

Comment: I'm afraid the answer is "you can't", as of Go 1.21. Interfaces with type terms can be used only as constraints, parametrized types require instantiation, etc. the same limitations you already know

Comment: If I may venture to elaborate, the statically typed nature of Go makes it tempting for those more accustomed to dynamic types to try to generalize everything.  But in practice this is rarely necessary, and the times you do (eg formatting or JSON encoding) reflect is the typical approach to generalities. Ask yourself, is there a "business logic" case for what you're trying to do here, or does putting disparate unspecified cases together in arbitrary combinations just come naturally to you?

Answer (score 3):

Instantiations of generic types with unique type parameters are different types. We need a way to create a slice with elements these different types.

Go's type parameter feature does not provide a non-generic type that represents all instantiations of some type, but Go does have the basic interface feature that we've known since the earliest days of Go. That's what we use here.

We define a slice of `interface { run(*testing.T) }` and fill the slice with values of instantiated types where the type has the required `run` method.

```
type sortTestCase[T constraints.Ordered] struct {
    input, want []T
}

func (tc sortTestCase[T]) run(t *testing.T) {
    got := MergeSort(tc.input)
    if !cmp.Equal(tc.want, got) {
        t.Fatalf(`Expected %v got %v`, tc.want, got)
    }       
}

func TestSort(t *testing.T) {
    testCases := map[string]interface{ run(t *testing.T) }{
        "ints": sortTestCase[int]{
            input: []int{3, 2, 5, 1, 4, 6},
            want:  []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6},
        },
        "strings": sortTestCase[string]{
            input: []string{"hello", "bonjour"},
            want:  []string{"bonjour", "hello"},
        },
    }
    for n, tc := range testCases {
        t.Run(n, tc.run)
    }
}
```

[Run the test on the playground!](https://go.dev/play/p/MQhPBf0pC3v)

---

A comment suggests that the answer can be improved by using a named type for the interface instead of the anonymous interface. Here's the code with that suggested change.

```
type sortTestCase[T constraints.Ordered] struct {
    input, want []T
}

func (tc sortTestCase[T]) run(t *testing.T) {
    got := MergeSort(tc.input)
    if !cmp.Equal(tc.want, got) {
        t.Fatalf(`Expected %v got %v`, tc.want, got)
    }       
}

func TestSort(t *testing.T) {
    type runtester interface{ run(t *testing.T) }
    var sortTestCases = map[string]runtester{
        "ints": sortTestCase[int]{
            input: []int{3, 2, 5, 1, 4, 6},
            want:  []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6},
        },
        "strings": sortTestCase[string]{
             input: []string{"hello", "bonjour"},
             want:  []string{"bonjour", "hello"},
        },
    }
    for n, tc := range testCases {
        t.Run(n, tc.run)
    }
}
```

Comment: clever. the code becomes a bit convoluted but I guess this answers the OP's question. It can be made a bit better by defining the interface instead of using an anonymous one.